# Angular validation messages flicker with ngAnimate and ngForm

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue with angularjs' input validation. Here's a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AQxNd18Z1j8NUrqZbScH?p=preview) to demonstrate it.

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form>
    <div ng-form="myForm">
      <input name="myInput" ng-model="name" required>
      <br>
      <span style="color: red;" ng-if="myForm.myInput.$error.required">This param is missing</span>
      <span style="color: red;" ng-if="!myForm.myInput.$error.required">This param is not missing</span>
    </div>  
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Script.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']).
  controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {

  });
```

This code is a bit artificial, but it shows what the problem is. I have to use ngForm, because in my project the form fields are generated dynamically with ngRepeat. Anyway, try typing something inside input, then clear it and you'll see how the validation spans flicker. It only happens with ngAnimate module injected into myApp. I can't remove it since I need it for other purposes. How can I get rid of this unwanted validation's animation?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - I think he is talking about the unwanted flicker between the two states as it appears that for a brief instance that both ng statements are true

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - DeclanMcD is right, it's as if for a moment both ng-ifs are true. Try removing 'ngAnimate' injection from javaScript and you'll see the difference.

Comment: There is no difference with and without nganimate for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take the two span tags out of the form div it works as expected.

```
    <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller="ctrl">
      <form>
        <div ng-form="myForm">
          <input name="myInput" ng-model="name" required>
          <br>

        </div>  

<span style="color: red;" ng-if="myForm.myInput.$error.required">This param is missing</span>
          <span style="color: red;" ng-if="!myForm.myInput.$error.required">This param is not missing</span>
      </form>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: This fixed the issue. Thank you very much!